# RESTful services layer not being mapped by Jetty embedded

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jetty

I'm running a web application in an embedded instance of Jetty. The application has been implemented with Vaadin along with a layer of RESTful services. Everything seems fine except that the services layer is not accessible. All requests to this layer seems to be handled by the Vaading servlet, instead of being handled by the Jersey servlet.

It seems that the problem is not related to the loading of the file `web.xml`, since other elements declared in that file, such as listeners, are working properly. What baffles me is that the services layer works correctly when the server is not running as an embedded instance (every request is dispatched by the right servlet).

The code I'm using is the following:

```
this.server = new Server();
ServerConnector httpConnector = new ServerConnector(this.server);
httpConnector.setHost("localhost");
httpConnector.setPort(this.port);
httpConnector.setIdleTimeout(30000);
server.addConnector(httpConnector);

WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/");
if (resourcePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".war")) {
    webapp.setWar(resourcePath);
} else {
    webapp.setResourceBase(resourcePath);
    webapp.setDescriptor(resourcePath + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");                
}

webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

this.server.setHandler(webapp);
this.server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
this.server.start();
```

I also tried to add the servlets' handlers programatically, but it didn't work. I wrote something like this:

```
ServletHolder vaadinHolder = new ServletHolder(
    "Application",
    com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.server.ApplicationServlet.class);
vaadinHolder.setInitParameter("application", "com.yyy.MyApplication");
webapp.addServlet(vaadinHolder, "/*");

ServletHolder jerseyHolder = new ServletHolder(
    "JerseyServices",
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.class);
jerseyHolder.setInitParameter(
    "com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "com.yyy.services");
jerseyHolder.setInitOrder(1);
webapp.addServlet(jerseyHolder, "/resources/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. It was related to the *ContextPath*. As soon as I replaced the value `/` (*root context*) with the context name chosen for this application, all began to work properly.

```
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/app-context");
```

I leave the comment here in case it is useful in the future.